# repeat the nth element every other n in a sequence

Tags: r, vector, insert

the original vector `x`:

```
x = 1:20
```

and what i look for is a vector `y` that repeats the n-th element in `x` every other n, for instance, when `n=4`:

```
n = 4
y = c(1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,11,12,12,13,14,15,16,16,17,18,19,20,20)
```

i'm actually doing it for matrices and i think it relates to the use of `apply` here when `margin=2` but couldn't figure it out right off the bat,
could anyone kindly show me a quick solution?

Comment: `x <- 1:20; sort(c(x, seq(x[4], max(x), 4)))`

Comment: @alistaire nice, but to be clear that only works if `x` is itself sorted

Comment: @MichaelChirico `x <- 1:20; sort(c(x, x[seq(4, length(x), 4)]))`? The order would be off, but the set would be right.

Comment: @alistaire suppose we wanted to repeat every 4th element of `y = sample(20)`. Your approach can be used as an index: `y[sort(...)]`

Comment: Ah, `x[sort(c(seq_along(x), seq(4, length(x), 4)))]`. Better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can also use

```
v1 <- rep(1, length(x))
v1[c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)] <- 2
rep(x, v1)
#[1]  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  9 10 11 12 12 13 14 15 16 16 17 18 19 20 20
```

Or as @MichaelChirico commented, the 2nd line of code can be made more general with

```
v1[seq_along(v1) %% n == 0L] = 2
```

Or in a one-liner with `ifelse` (from @JonathanCarroll's comments)

```
rep(x, ifelse(seq_along(x) %% n, 1, 2))
```

Comment: nice approach! I would use `v1[seq_along(v1) %% 4L == 0L] = 2` since that's more extensible (to general `n`)

Comment: Or avoid creating something that you need to store/update: `rep(x, ifelse(seq_along(x) %% n, 1, 2))`

Comment: @JonathanCarroll skip slow `ifelse`: `(seq_along(x) %% n == 0) + 1L`

Comment: Depends how much of an issue speed is, but yeah; that's neat (at a small cost to being readable).

Comment: or go meta-`rep` -- `rep(x, rep(rep(1:2, c(n-1, 1)), ceiling(length(x)/n))`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed matrices are the way to go

```
duplast = function(M) rbind(M, M[nrow(M), ])
c(duplast(matrix(x, nrow = 4L)))
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  7  8  8  9 10 11 12 12 13 14 15 16 16 17 18 19 20
# [25] 20
```

If you wanted to use `apply`:

```
c(apply(matrix(x, nrow = 4L), 2L, function(C) c(C, C[length(C)])))
```